# Index out of bounds while trying to call on a ListView column header

Tags: excel, vba, listview

I'm trying to see if a ColumnHeader already exists before adding it to my ListView, but when I try to automate the process it gives me an index out of bounds error. The code works fine If I manually put the index number, but if I put it in a variable for the index number it gives out the error. Someone knows why?

```
    Private Sub Salvar()
        Dim Lv As ListItem
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer
        i = Cadastro_Pedido.ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Count - 1
        Set Lv = Cadastro_Pedido.ListView1.ListItems.Add(Text:=("Fixo"))
            Lv.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Adicionar_Fixo.TextBox4.Text
            Lv.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Adicionar_Fixo.TextBox5.Text
            Lv.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Adicionar_Fixo.TextBox6.Text
            Lv.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Adicionar_Fixo.TextBox1.Text
            Lv.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Adicionar_Fixo.ComboBox1.Value
            Lv.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Adicionar_Fixo.ComboBox2.Value
            If Adicionar_Fixo.ComboBox3.Value <> "SEMPRE PERGUNTAR" Then
                For j = 0 To i
                    If Cadastro_Pedido.ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Item(j).Text = "Lado Liso" Then
                        GoTo proxima_linha
                    End If
                Next j
                Cadastro_Pedido.ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="Lado Liso", Width:=50
    proxima_linha:
                Lv.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Adicionar_Fixo.ComboBox3.Value
            End If
            
     End Sub
```